# How to format Spring REST JSON output

Tags: json, spring

I am working on Java Spring REST API which gives a JSON output something like this:

```
{
    "speed1mbps": null,
    "speed10mbps": null,
    "speed100mbps": null,
    "speed1000mbps": null,
    "phone": null,
    "NAME": "some name",
    "STREET": "ST address",
    "city": "somecity",
    "state": "some state",
    "zip": "232409",
}
```

but I need the formatted JSON output as below.

```
{   
    speed:[
        1mbps:null
        10mbps:null
        100mbps:null
        1000mbps:null
        1000mbps:null
    ],
    "phone": null,
    "NAME": "some name",
    "STREET": "ST address",
    "city": "somecity",
    "state": "some state",
    "zip": "232409",
}
```

Is it possible to format the JSON? Please let me know how to format the JSON.

Comment: What you want is not valid JSON.

Comment: Also, there is no sign of any Java within three miles of this question.  I am removing that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom dto if you want to format the JSON as you want, plese see below example:

```
class Dto {
    private Map<String, String> speeds;
    private String phone;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
}
```

Then you can add entries in speeds like...

```
speeds.put("1mbps", null);
speeds.put("10mbps", null);
speeds.put("100mbps", null);
speeds.put("1000mbps", null);
```

Then the valid JSON result will be....

```
{   
    speeds:{
        1mbps:null,
        10mbps:null,
        100mbps:null,
        1000mbps:null,
        1000mbps:null
    },
    "phone": null,
    "NAME": "some name",
    "STREET": "ST address",
    "city": "somecity",
    "state": "some state",
    "zip": "232409",
}
```

This is the class you should return to your REST response.

Comment: Thanks, That made sense of adding a custom DTO but how do I map the fields when I am using Hibernate. Do, I put the speeds in separate DTO and  populate  speeds.put("1mbps", sppeds.get1mbps());? something like this?

Comment: If you have the entity (SPPEDS) with the property of 1mpbs, 10mbps and so on, then map that entity to your db table using hibernate and then once you retrieve the info of that entity then you dto.getSpeeds().put("1mbps", sppeds.get1mbps()) and so on and then return the dto as your response.

Comment: I made the changes It looks fine but it is failing because I am not able to map the speeds map with hibernate it is throwing error of could not determine type for: Map, at table so, how do I avoid this ?

Comment: Hi @Raj, do not map the Dto to your db table, map the entity (SPPEDS) instead. Please see related concept here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688570/want-nested-json-format-from-hibernate-json-response/42688793?noredirect=1#comment72500838_42688793