# want nested json format from hibernate json response

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

I have json response like below

```
[{"Name":"kannur hub","Amount":1840.00},{"Name":"Calicut Hub","Amount":7000.00}]
```

i want a json like this instead of the above format

```
[{"name":"kannur hub","TotalAmount":1840,"child":[{"sub":"Sale Of Products @ 12 % Tax","amount":345,"sub":"sos","amount":1020,"sub":"Boss","amount":475}]},{"name":"Calicut Hub","TotalAmount":7000,"child":[{sub":"cop","amount":3500,"sub":"SALES ACCOUNT","amount":3500}]}]
```

So whenever i retrieve children grouping from hibernate projections,the result removes the sum value and return individual values

```
[{"sub":"Boss","Name":"kannur hub","Amount":475.00},{"sub":"sos","Name":"kannur hub","Amount":1020.00},{"sub":"cop","Name":"Calicut Hub","Amount":3500.00},{"sub":"SALES ACCOUNT","Name":"Calicut Hub","Amount":3500.00},{"sub":"Sale Of Products @ 12 % Tax","Name":"kannur hub","Amount":345.00}]
```

hibernate query is,

```
ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
        proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("offId.officeProfileName").as("Name"));
        proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("accId.accHeadName").as("sub"));
        proj.add(Projections.sum("accountsDataValue").as("Amount"));
        crit.setProjection(proj);
```

Iam using spring boot application and postgresql database with java 1.8 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom DTO if you want to achieve the json results you want, please see example below.

```
class Child {
    String sub;
    Long amount;
}

class Dto {
   String name;
   Long totalAmount;
   List<Child> child;
}
```

then compose your Dto and add necessary children. Below are the example, assumed that you already have the results from db:

if your rs return is `List<Child>` then you can do this..

```
Dto dto = new Dto();
dto.addAll(rs);
dto.setName("name");
dto.setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
return dto;
```

or if rs result is not `List<Child>` you can do this...

```
Dto dto = new Dto();
//assumed rs contains the db child results.
for(int i=0; i<rs.length; i++) {
    Child child = new Child(rs.get("sub"), rs.get("amount"))
    dto.getChild().add(child)
}
dto.setName("name");
dto.setTotalAmount(totalAmount);
return dto;
```

The valid resulting JSON is like below:

```
{
        "name":"kannur hub",
        "TotalAmount":1840,
        "child":[
            {
                "sub":"Sale Of Products @ 12 % Tax",
                "amount":345,
            },
            {
                "sub":"sos",
                "amount":1020,
            },
            {
                "sub":"Boss",
                "amount":475
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Calicut Hub",
        "TotalAmount":7000,
        "child":[
            {
                "sub":"cop",
                "amount":3500
            },
            {
                "sub":"SALES ACCOUNT",
                "amount":3500
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: could you be more specific especially after the creation of DTO classes